# App absolutely refuses to use proxy for localhost requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, proxy, webclient, fiddler

I have Fiddler running on port 8888

Web.config:

```
  <system.net>
      <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
          <proxy bypassonlocal="False" proxyaddress="http://localhost:8888" usesystemdefault="False" autoDetect="False" />
      </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

App code (specifies credentials for the API controller its talking to):

```
            var wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri($"http://localhost:8888"), false);
            wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myuser", "mypass");
            var response = wc.UploadString("http://localhost:11026/api/mycontroller/mymethod", "POST", request);
```

I cannot for the life of me get it to communicate via Fiddler so I can debug requests. Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**
This information is supplied by Fiddler [help](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/observe-traffic/troubleshooting/notraffictolocalhost) but having used localhost.fiddler in both web.config and app code, still not being captured by Fiddler (and when Fiddler is closed it doesn't cause a connection failed error)

> Solution 2: Use http://ipv4.fiddler
>
> Use http://ipv4.fiddler to hit localhost on the IPv4 adapter. This
>   works especially well with the Visual Studio test webserver (codename:
>   Cassini) because the test server only listens on the IPv4 loopback
>   adapter. Use http://ipv6.fiddler to hit localhost on the IPv6 adapter,
>   or use http://localhost.fiddler to hit localhost using "localhost" in
>   the Host header. This last option should work best with IIS Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to send it via the proxy, send it via one of the fiddler loopbacks.

Such as http://fiddler.ipv4:11026 ... ...

Details are given here:

http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/observe-traffic/troubleshooting/notraffictolocalhost

Shows how to set it up and capture traffic.  It is the method I've used when I want to see traffic being passed between local web apis and my Mvc project

Comment: Thought this would be the answer... but absolutely no difference :( I have updated my question

Comment: Apologies, it was the server (request) URL that I was supposed to change, not the proxy URL - which worked. Thank you. Now I just need to fix the `400. The request hostname is invalid` issue :P